# elementwise-diff utility for (simple) structures of data

Tags: software-development, command-line, diff, utility

Suppose I have a data structure made up of, say, a 32-bit floating-point value and a 32-bit integer values. Now suppose I have two files with a million of these structures in each. For simplicity let's assume there no header, no anything - just these plain structs.

I want a utility which will tell me at which indices the files differ, with the differing value pairs printed. I'm not very concerned about the format, as long as its readable by a human (and thus parsable).

Naturally, this is not difficult to implement on your own. Still - if there's some kind of popular/commonplace utility which does this - I'm interested.

Required features:

- Gratis
- Libre
- Works on Linux
- Works from the command-line

Desired features:

- Actively maintained
- Cross-platform
- Isn't written in an esoteric language
- Supports showing only the first difference, just the maximum difference etc.
- Supports just listing the position of the difference
- Supports treating the input data as a multi-dimensional array (e.g. 500x2000 structs rather than 1000000 structs) and referring to the coordinates
- Can handle files on non-equal length, e.g. either ignore the excess elements in one of the files, or declare them all to be differences.

Note:

- The utility should *not* compute the edit-distance between the two files, i.e. not tell me "if you add an element here and remove an element there they would be equal". It should be strictly elementwise. So, not like the `diff` utility.

Comment: Are you saying that you can assume that there are an identical number of structures in the two files? If not then how are you doing "elementwise" comparisons? If you are assuming that, then isn't this just a matter of looping over the two files? A 2 line awk script cold do this for textual representations of the structures. If the structures are padded (or are stored in binary), then the `cmp -v` would point out the differences.

Comment: @icarus : "Are you saying" etc. - yes, sort of. I was assuming that for simplicity. If the tool doesn't need that assumption, then great; see edit.

Comment: "A 2 line awk script cold do this for textual representations of the structures. " <- But I'm not talking about a textual representation.

Comment: I am confident that there is no well known utility that can take a description of an arbitrary data structure and do what you want. GNU `poke` https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/poke.git/tree/README is probably as close as you are going to get. Of course I am just a random person on the internet and new to this particular SE. I would write the small program (C, Python, whatever you are happy with) and move on.